# highcharts clickable labels how to goto anchor

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts within my Backbone application to display some information in a column graph.

I use the datalabels in the chart to allow the user to click on and move to the detail page of that datapoint. This is not a normal window.location call, but should be a window.location.hash call. This is because I want to move to an anchor, which will be picked up by my Backbone router.

This is what a typical  label (using the formatter) is transformed into:

```
<tspan onclick="location.href=&quot;/#/test/1&quot;" style="cursor: pointer; " x="360">Sectie nummer 6</tspan>
```

So in other words, is it possible to have Highcharts do a onclick="window.location.hash=..." instead of location.href?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try adding the click listener using Javascript (so not as an attribute)?

Comment: yes that does not work, as all <a href...> elements are translated to the tspan items with an onclick event handler in it. (as above). It is simply transformed into another element. attributes as an id aren't included.

Comment: I did however just edit the source of highcharts and replaced all location.href instances with window.location.hash
That seems to do the trick for me for now. But is does not deserve the price for best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution (not the most cross-browser solution because of its dependency on `<text>` but you can get it working with the incompatible IE versions)

```
$(".highcharts-data-labels").on("click", "text", function() {
    window.location.hash = "anchor";
});
```

[Why *`jQuery.on()`*?](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/ZuqGZ/)

Comment: Hi Jugal, thanks for the answer and example. I'll award the points to you.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.hash="comment-16513878"` & `window.location="#comment-16513878"` appear to have the same result. Have you tried that?

```
formatter: function() {
    return '<a href="#somePlaceHolder" >' + this.y + '</a>';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/BUxMZ/

Comment: it is not window.location that highcharts is using, it is location.href, which causes a complete new page load in the browser.