# Move flags tooltip to upper side

Tags: highcharts

I have Highstock chart with flags. Everything is fine but I wanted to change the position of the tooltip of the flags. (Move tooltip of flags to upper side of the flags). And also i want to give link to flags text "**Test test**", which will open in new tab. Can any one help me? This my full code http://jsfiddle.net/anant_ghate/8byc9/1/

```
// Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        tooltip: {
            positioner: function(boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {
                return {
                    x: point.plotX + 20,
                    y: point.plotY + -20
                };
            },
            shared:true,
            formatter: function(){
                    var p = '';
                    if(this.point) {
                      p += '<span>'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.point.x) +'</span><br/>';
                      p += '<b>'+ this.point.title + '</b>' // This will add the text on the flags
                    }
                    else {              
                      p += '<b>'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +'</b><br/>';
                      $.each(this.points, function(i, series){
                        p += '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">' + this.series.name + '</span>: <b>'+ this.y;
                      });

                    }
                    return p;
            },              
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Exchange rate'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: data,
            id: 'dataseries',
            tooltip: {
                yDecimals: 4
            }
        }, {
            type: 'flags',
            data: [{
                x: Date.UTC(2011, 1, 20),
                title: 'Test test'
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2011, 3, 20),
                title: 'Test test'
            }],
            onSeries: 'dataseries',
            allowPointSelect : true,
            shape: 'squarepin',
            y : -40         
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tweak the tooltip like in this answer [Highcharts tooltip always on right side of cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966286/highcharts-tooltip-always-on-right-side-of-cursor/11975793#11975793)

And make the flags clickable with an approach similar to this [highcharts clickable labels how to goto anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307443/highcharts-clickable-labels-how-to-goto-anchor/12329557#12329557)

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to a url when clicking a flag you can create a function on the "click-event":
http://jsfiddle.net/8byc9/5/
I don't think it will be easy to create your own positioner only for the flag-tooltip but not for the currencytooltip...