# Link inside label tag of high charts doesn't open up in a new tab, tried both target = "_blank" and rel="external"

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
        chart = $('#queue_report').highcharts({
          chart: {
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            events: {
              load: function () {
                chart = this;
                var ren = this.renderer,
                ren.label('<a href="http://devservices.csnzoo.com:15672/#/queues/storm_queues/oms_pre_process_order" target="_blank" >oms_validation_pre_sa</a>', 250, 60)
                    .attr({
                      fill: '#7b2d66',
                      stroke: 'white',
                      'stroke-width': 2,
                      padding: 5,
                      r: 5
                    })
                    .css({
                      color: 'white',
                      width: '100px'
                    })
                    .add(data.all_queues_data[0][0])
                    .shadow(true);
```

Warning log:
[Fri Jul 17 2015 09:40:11 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] runRoute get #/queues/storm_queues/oms_pre_process_order
sammy-0.6.0.min.js:5

[Fri Jul 17 2015 09:40:11 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] 404 Not Found 
get #/queues/storm_queues/oms_pre_process_order  Error: 404 Not Found 
get #/queues/storm_queues/oms_pre_process_order

So, I resolved the issue. Just add an attribute on to the label. Hope this helps.

```
                  ren.label('oms_pre_process_order<br/>' + 'Messages:' + data.all_queues_data[26][1] + ' ' + 'Errors:' + data.all_queues_data[28][1], 40, 240)
                      .attr({
                        fill: '#ba3025',
                        stroke: 'white',
                        'stroke-width': 2,
                        padding: 5,
                        r: 5
                      })
                      .css({
                        color: 'white',
                        width: '100px'
                      })
                      .on('click',function(){
                        var win = window.open("http://devservices.csnzoo.com:15672/#/queues/storm_queues/oms_pre_process_order", '_blank');
                        win.focus();
                      })
                      .add(data.all_queues_data[0][0])
                      .shadow(true);
```

Comment: Highcharts adds a click event handler to labels. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307443/highcharts-clickable-labels-how-to-goto-anchor might help you

Comment: I got the solution @JuliaWill thanks for help